# Two pages built identically, now experiencing different results

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Working with two separate legacy webpages in a visual basic website utilizing MS-SQL. Long story short, the first page only displays the "latest issue" (which is working correctly). While the second page "used" to serve as an Archive, always showing the latest issue first, followed by all the past issues. At some point, the Archive page reverted to showing only 2014 and older issues - which as you can see is 2 years late.

At this point, I'm stuck. I can't figure out why two pages using mostly the same imports/classes - gives a different result when it comes to year. If someone could throw me a bone/point me in the right direction, I'd appreciate it. Part of learning is knowing when to ask for help =)

**Working "First" page .aspx.vb - Shows latest issue correctly**

```vb
    Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls
    Imports System.IO
    Imports System.Data
    Imports System.Data.SqlClient
    Imports System.Web

    Partial Class inprint_latestissue
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page



Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    'YearLinks.Text = GetYearLinks()'


End Sub

Dim lastIssueDate As String = Nothing
Dim lastIssueID As Integer = 0
Dim lastCategory As String = Nothing
Dim bookText As String = ""
Dim onlineextraText As String = ""
Dim onlineextracount As Integer = 0
Dim bookcount As Integer = 0
Dim extraText As String = ""

Protected Function AddGroupingRowIssue() As String
    Dim currentIssueDate As String = Eval("iDatePublished").ToString()
    Dim currentIssueID As String = Eval("iID").ToString()
    Dim currentVolume As String = Eval("vName").ToString()
    Dim currentIssue As String = Eval("iName").ToString()
    Dim coverImage = "/img/imgLibrary/Covers/cover" + currentVolume + "0" + currentIssue + "sm.jpg"
    If File.Exists(Server.MapPath(coverImage)) Then
        coverImage = "<img src='/img/imgLibrary/Covers/cover" + currentVolume + "0" + currentIssue + "sm.jpg' style='float:right;margin:0px 20px 5px 5px;'/>"
    Else
        coverImage = ""
    End If

    If currentIssueDate.Length = 0 Then
        currentIssueDate = ""
    End If

    If lastIssueDate <> currentIssueDate Then
        Dim IssueRecipes As String = GetRecipes(lastIssueID)
        lastIssueDate = currentIssueDate
        lastIssueID = currentIssueID
        Return String.Format(IssueRecipes + "</ul><br clear='both'/><h2>{0}</h2>" + coverImage + "<ul>", currentIssueDate)

    Else
        Return String.Empty
    End If
End Function

Protected Function GetStoryType() As String
    Dim category As String = Eval("arArticleCategoryID").ToString()
    Dim arID As String = Eval("arID").ToString()
    Dim arTitle As String = Eval("arTitle").ToString()
    Dim arPublicStatus As String = Eval("arPublicStatus").ToString()
    Dim arVideoURL As String = Eval("arVideoURL2").ToString()
    Dim returnText As String = ""
    Dim videoText As String = ""
    Dim subscriberText As String = ""

    If arVideoURL <> "" Then
        videoText = " <a href='/features/article.aspx?arID=" & Eval("arID") & "#video' CssClass='videolink'><img src='/img/icon-video.gif' alt='Watch video' /></a>"
    End If
    If arPublicStatus = "0" Then
        subscriberText = " <img src='/img/icon-subscriber.gif' alt='subscriber-only' width='16' height='16' />"
    End If

    Select Case category

        Case 1
            returnText = "<li>Gardening: <a href='/features/article.aspx?arID=" + arID + "'>" + arTitle + "</a>" + videoText + subscriberText + "</li>"
        Case 2
            returnText = "<li>What's In Season: <a href='/features/article.aspx?arID=" + arID + "'>" + arTitle + "</a>" + videoText + subscriberText + "</li>"
        Case 3
            returnText = "<li>California Country Close-Up: <a href='/features/article.aspx?arID=" + arID + "'>" + arTitle + "</a>" + videoText + subscriberText + "</li>"
        Case 4
            bookText = bookText + "<a href='/features/article.aspx?arID=" + arID + "'>" + arTitle + "</a>" + subscriberText + "<br />"
            'returnText = "Book Review: "
        Case 11
            onlineextraText = onlineextraText + "<li><a href='/features/article.aspx?arID=" + arID + "'>" + arTitle + "</a>" + videoText + subscriberText + "</li>"
        Case 15
            returnText = "<li>On location: <a href='/features/article.aspx?arID=" + arID + "'>" + arTitle + "</a>" + videoText + subscriberText + "</li>"
        Case 16
            returnText = "<li>It's a bountiful life: <a href='/features/article.aspx?arID=" + arID + "'>" + arTitle + "</a>" + videoText + subscriberText + "</li>"
        Case 13
            returnText = "<li>Farmer &amp; Foodie: <a href='/features/article.aspx?arID=" + arID + "'>" + arTitle + "</a>" + videoText + subscriberText + "</li>"
        Case 19
            returnText = "<li>From the editors: <a href='/features/article.aspx?arID=" + arID + "'>" + arTitle + "</a>" + videoText + subscriberText + "</li>"
        Case 21
            returnText = "<li>Fresh ideas: <a href='/features/article.aspx?arID=" + arID + "'>" + arTitle + "</a>" + videoText + subscriberText + "</li>"
        Case 17
            returnText = "<li>Health and wellness: <a href='/features/article.aspx?arID=" + arID + "'>" + arTitle + "</a>" + videoText + subscriberText + "</li>"
        Case Else
            returnText = "<li><a href='/features/article.aspx?arID=" + arID + "'>" + arTitle + "</a>" + videoText + subscriberText + "</li>"
    End Select


    'If lastCategory <> category Then
    'If lastCategory = "4" Then
    'bookText = bookText.Substring(0, (bookText.Length() - 2))
    'bookText = bookText.Replace(subscriberText + ",", subscriberText)
    'returnText = "<li>Book Reviews: " + bookText + "</li>" + returnText
    'bookText = ""
    'End If

    'lastCategory = category
    'End If

    If category = "4" Then
        If bookcount = 0 Then
            'bookText = bookText.Substring(0, (bookText.Length() - 2))
            returnText = "<li>Book Reviews:<br />" + bookText
        Else
            'bookText = bookText.Substring(0, (bookText.Length() - 2))
            returnText = bookText

        End If
        bookText = ""
        bookcount = bookcount + 1
        lastCategory = category
    End If

    If category = "11" Then
        If onlineextracount = 0 Then
            returnText = "</ul><h3>Online Extras</h3><ul>" + onlineextraText
        Else
            returnText = onlineextraText
        End If
        onlineextraText = ""
        onlineextracount = onlineextracount + 1
    End If


    Return returnText

End Function




Protected Function GetRecipes(ByVal currentIssueDate As Integer) As String
    'Dim currentIssueDate As String = Eval("iID").ToString()

    Dim returnText As String = ""
    Dim recipeText As String = ""

    Dim conn As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("CFBFConnectionString").ConnectionString)
    Dim comm As New SqlCommand("select rid,rTitle from Recipes where (rIssueID=@id and rLive=1) order by rTitle", conn)

    comm.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@id", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = currentIssueDate

    Try
        conn.Open()
        Dim reader = comm.ExecuteReader()
        While reader.Read
            recipeText = recipeText + "<li><a href='/recipes/recipes.aspx?rID=" + reader.Item(0).ToString() + "'>" + reader.Item(1) + "</a></li>"
        End While


    Catch e As Exception

    End Try

    If recipeText <> "" Then

        recipeText = recipeText.Substring(0, (recipeText.Length() - 2))
        returnText = "</ul><h3>Recipes</h3><ul>" + recipeText + "</ul>"

    End If


    Return returnText

End Function


Protected Sub ListView_articleList_DataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ListViewItemEventArgs)


End Sub
Protected Sub ListView_articleList_PreRender(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)



End Sub

Protected Function GetYearLinks() As String

    Dim returnText As String = ""
    Dim yearLinks As String = ""
    Dim thisYear As String = ""

    Dim conn As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("CFBFConnectionString").ConnectionString)
    Dim comm As New SqlCommand("select vName from Volume order by vName DESC", conn)


    Try
        conn.Open()
        Dim reader = comm.ExecuteReader()
        While reader.Read
            thisYear = (reader.Item(0) - 28) + 2005
            yearLinks = yearLinks + "<a href='?vName=" + reader.Item(0).ToString() + "'>" + thisYear + "</a> |"
        End While


    Catch e As Exception

    End Try

    yearLinks = yearLinks.Substring(0, (yearLinks.Length() - 2))
    returnText = yearLinks

    Return returnText

End Function




Protected Sub ArticlesList_OnSelecting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ObjectDataSourceSelectingEventArgs) Handles ObjectDataSource_ArticlesList.Selecting



    e.InputParameters("iID") = GetLastIssueID()
End Sub

Protected Function GetLastIssueID() As Integer
    Dim thisIssue As Integer
    Dim conn As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("CFBFConnectionString").ConnectionString)
    'Dim comm As New SqlCommand("select top 1 iID from Issue order by iID desc", conn)
    'Dim comm As New SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 1 iID  FROM Issue  where iID not in (select top 1 iID from Issue order by iID desc)  order by iID desc", conn)
    Dim comm As New SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 1 iID FROM Issue WHERE iLive=1 ORDER BY iID DESC", conn)

    conn.Open()
    Dim reader = comm.ExecuteReader()
    While reader.Read
        thisIssue = reader.Item(0)
    End While
    'Preview new issue thisIssue = 55

    Return thisIssue
End Function

Protected Sub ArticlesList_OnSelected(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ObjectDataSourceStatusEventArgs) Handles ObjectDataSource_ArticlesList.Selected

    If e.Exception Is Nothing AndAlso e.ReturnValue IsNot Nothing Then
        e.AffectedRows = DirectCast(e.ReturnValue, DataTable).Rows.Count
        If e.AffectedRows = 0 Then

        Else
            lastRecipes.Text = GetRecipes(GetLastIssueID())
        End If
    End If

End Sub


    End Class
```

**Archive page - For some reason, showing latest results as year 2014**

```vb
    Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls
    Imports System.IO
    Imports System.Data
    Imports System.Data.SqlClient
    Imports System.Web

    Partial Class inprint_archives
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    YearLinks.Text = GetYearLinks()

End Sub

Dim lastIssueDate As String = Nothing
Dim lastIssueID As Integer = 0
Dim lastCategory As String = Nothing
Dim bookText As String = ""
Dim onlineextraText As String = ""
Dim onlineextracount As Integer = 0
Dim bookcount As Integer = 0
Dim extraText As String = ""

Protected Function AddGroupingRowIssue() As String
    Dim currentIssueDate As String = Eval("iDatePublished").ToString()
    Dim currentIssueID As String = Eval("iID").ToString()
    Dim currentVolume As String = Eval("vName").ToString()
    Dim currentIssue As String = Eval("iName").ToString()
    Dim coverImage = "/img/imgLibrary/Covers/cover" + currentVolume + "0" + currentIssue + "sm.jpg"
    If File.Exists(Server.MapPath(coverImage)) Then
        coverImage = "<img src='/img/imgLibrary/Covers/cover" + currentVolume + "0" + currentIssue + "sm.jpg' style='float:right;margin:0px 20px 5px 5px;'/>"
    Else
        coverImage = ""
    End If

    If currentIssueDate.Length = 0 Then
        currentIssueDate = ""
    End If

    If lastIssueDate <> currentIssueDate Then
        Dim IssueRecipes As String = GetRecipes(lastIssueID)
        lastIssueDate = currentIssueDate
        lastIssueID = currentIssueID
        Return String.Format(IssueRecipes + "</ul><br clear='both'/><h2>{0}</h2>" + coverImage + "<ul>", currentIssueDate)

    Else
        Return String.Empty
    End If
End Function

Protected Function GetStoryType() As String
    Dim category As String = Eval("arArticleCategoryID").ToString()
    Dim arID As String = Eval("arID").ToString()
    Dim arTitle As String = Eval("arTitle").ToString()
    Dim arPublicStatus As String = Eval("arPublicStatus").ToString()
    Dim arVideoURL As String = Eval("arVideoURL2").ToString()
    Dim returnText As String = ""
    Dim videoText As String = ""
    Dim subscriberText As String = ""


    If arVideoURL <> "" Then
        videoText = " <a href='/features/article.aspx?arID=" & Eval("arID") & "#video' CssClass='videolink'><img src='/img/icon-video.gif' alt='Watch video' /></a>"
    End If
    If arPublicStatus = "0" Then
        subscriberText = " <img src='/img/icon-subscriber.gif' alt='subscriber-only' width='16' height='16' />"

    End If

    Select Case category
        Case 1
            returnText = "<li>Gardening: <a href='/features/article.aspx?arID=" + arID + "'>" + arTitle + "</a>" + videoText + subscriberText + "</li>"
        Case 2
            returnText = "<li>What's In Season: <a href='/features/article.aspx?arID=" + arID + "'>" + arTitle + "</a>" + videoText + subscriberText + "</li>"
        Case 3
            returnText = "<li>California Country Close-Up: <a href='/features/article.aspx?arID=" + arID + "'>" + arTitle + "</a>" + videoText + subscriberText + "</li>"
        Case 4
            bookText = bookText + "<a href='/features/article.aspx?arID=" + arID + "'>" + arTitle + "</a>" + subscriberText + "<br />"
            'returnText = "<li>Book Review: <a href='/features/article.aspx?arID=" + arID + "'>" + arTitle + "</a>" + subscriberText + "</li>"
        Case 11
            onlineextraText = onlineextraText + "<li><a href='/features/article.aspx?arID=" + arID + "'>" + arTitle + "</a>" + videoText + subscriberText + "</li>"
        Case 15
            returnText = "<li>On location: <a href='/features/article.aspx?arID=" + arID + "'>" + arTitle + "</a>" + videoText + subscriberText + "</li>"
        Case 16
            returnText = "<li>It's a bountiful life: <a href='/features/article.aspx?arID=" + arID + "'>" + arTitle + "</a>" + videoText + subscriberText + "</li>"

        Case 13
            returnText = "<li>Farmer &amp; Foodie: <a href='/features/article.aspx?arID=" + arID + "'>" + arTitle + "</a>" + videoText + subscriberText + "</li>"
        Case Else
            onlineextracount = 0
            bookcount = 0
            returnText = "<li><a href='/features/article.aspx?arID=" + arID + "'>" + arTitle + "</a>" + videoText + subscriberText + "</li>"
    End Select


    If category = "4" Then
        If bookcount = 0 Then
            'bookText = bookText.Substring(0, (bookText.Length() - 2))
            returnText = "<li>Book Reviews:<br />" + bookText
        Else
            'bookText = bookText.Substring(0, (bookText.Length() - 2))
            returnText = bookText

        End If
        bookText = ""
        bookcount = bookcount + 1
        lastCategory = category
    End If

    If category = "11" Then
        If lastCategory = "4" Then
            returnText = "</li>"
        End If
        If onlineextracount = 0 Then
            returnText = returnText + "</ul><h3>Online Extras</h3><ul>" + onlineextraText
        Else
            returnText = onlineextraText
        End If
        onlineextraText = ""
        onlineextracount = onlineextracount + 1
    End If


    Return returnText

End Function






Protected Function GetRecipes(ByVal currentIssueDate) As String
    'Dim currentIssueDate As String = Eval("iID").ToString()

    Dim returnText As String = ""
    Dim recipeText As String = ""

    Dim conn As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("CFBFConnectionString").ConnectionString)
    Dim comm As New SqlCommand("select rid,rTitle from Recipes where (rIssueID=@id and rLive=1) order by rTitle", conn)

    comm.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@id", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = currentIssueDate

    Try
        conn.Open()
        Dim reader = comm.ExecuteReader()
        While reader.Read
            recipeText = recipeText + "<li><a href='/recipes/recipes.aspx?rID=" + reader.Item(0).ToString() + "'>" + reader.Item(1) + "</a></li>"
        End While


    Catch e As Exception

    End Try

    If recipeText <> "" Then

        recipeText = recipeText.Substring(0, (recipeText.Length() - 2))
        returnText = "</ul><h3>Recipes</h3><ul>" + recipeText + "</ul>"

    End If


    Return returnText

End Function


Protected Sub ListView_articleList_DataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ListViewItemEventArgs)

End Sub
Protected Sub ListView_articleList_PreRender(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim lblTot As Label = TryCast(Me.ListView_articleList.FindControl("lastRecipes"), Label)

    lblTot.Text = GetRecipes(lastIssueID)
End Sub

Protected Function GetYearLinks() As String

    Dim returnText As String = ""
    Dim yearLinks As String = ""
    Dim thisYear As String = ""

    Dim conn As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("CFBFConnectionString").ConnectionString)
    Dim comm As New SqlCommand("select vName from Volume order by vName DESC", conn)


    Try
        conn.Open()
        Dim reader = comm.ExecuteReader()
        While reader.Read
            thisYear = (reader.Item(0) - 28) + 2005
            'If (thisYear <> "2012") Then
            '   yearLinks = yearLinks + "<a href='?vName=" + reader.Item(0).ToString() + "'>" + thisYear + "</a> | "
            'End If
            yearLinks = yearLinks + "<a href='?vName=" + reader.Item(0).ToString() + "'>" + thisYear + "</a> | "
        End While


    Catch e As Exception

    End Try

    yearLinks = yearLinks.Substring(0, (yearLinks.Length() - 2))
    returnText = yearLinks

    Return returnText

End Function


End Class
```

Comment: What is returned from `select vName from Volume order by vName DESC`? And then applying the formula `thisYear = (reader.Item(0) - 28) + 2005` to those results?

Comment: That code first returns all the volumes currently in the database (currently we are at 39, but as far as this table is concerned it starts at 28). The second formula takes each of these volumes, and creates a link at the top of the page equivalent to the year for said volume. If you click said link, it will only show you issues equivalent to that volume of that year. If that all makes sense haha.

Comment: In other words, that routine isn't where your missing 2015-2016 is coming from?

Comment: Exactly. Sorry, I know that doesn't help much >.<

Comment: Have you checked the connectionstring both application are using? Are you sure they are connecting to the same database?